# FaultException with SlSvcUtil generated code

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7, wsdl

I have a WebService with following wsdl file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions name="BBAppWebAccessService" targetNamespace="com.test" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="com.test" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <wsdl:types>
  <xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="com.test" version="1.0" xmlns:tns="com.test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="getPOI" type="tns:getPOI" />
  <xs:element name="getPOIResponse" type="tns:getPOIResponse" />

  <xs:complexType name="poi">
  <xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="tns:poiPreview">
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="images" nillable="true" type="tns:bbImage" />
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="poiPreview">

      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="poiID" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="thumbsnails" nillable="true" type="tns:bbImage" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="bbImage">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="imageData" nillable="true" type="xs:byte" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="imageName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="imageID" type="xs:int" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="getPOI">
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" />
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="getPOIResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:poi" />
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getPOI">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:getPOI" name="parameters">
      </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getPOIResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:getPOIResponse" name="parameters">
      </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="BBAppWebAccess">
      <wsdl:operation name="getPOI">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:getPOI" name="getPOI">
      </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:getPOIResponse" name="getPOIResponse">
      </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BBAppWebAccessServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:BBAppWebAccess">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
      <wsdl:operation name="getPOI">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="getPOI">
          <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getPOIResponse">
          <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="BBAppWebAccessService">
      <wsdl:port binding="tns:BBAppWebAccessServiceSoapBinding" name="BBAppWebAccessPort">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/BBAppWeb/HelloWorld" />
      </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

I used the SlSvcUtil from the Windows Phone SDK to generate the proxy classes for c# `SlSvcUtil.exe test.wsdl`.

This is a part from the generated code:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getPOI", WrapperNamespace="com.test", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getPOI {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Order=0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public int ID;

        public getPOI() {
        }

        public getPOI(int ID) {
            this.ID = ID;
        }
}

private class BBAppWebAccessClientChannel : ChannelBase<BBAppWebAccess>, BBAppWebAccess
{

    public BBAppWebAccessClientChannel(System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<BBAppWebAccess> client) : 
            base(client)
    {
    }

    public System.IAsyncResult BegingetPOI(getPOI request, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        object[] _args = new object[1];
        _args[0] = request;
        System.IAsyncResult _result = base.BeginInvoke("getPOI", _args, callback, asyncState);
        return _result;
    }

    public getPOIResponse EndgetPOI(System.IAsyncResult result)
    {
        object[] _args = new object[0];
        getPOIResponse _result = ((getPOIResponse)(base.EndInvoke("getPOI", _args, result)));
        return _result;
    }
}
```

The *FaultException* is thrown by that `getPOIResponse _result = ((getPOIResponse)(base.EndInvoke("getPOI", _args, result)));`.

I call the WebService with following code:

```
private void Load_Initial_Data()
{
    try
    {
        BBAppWebAccessClient wac = new BBAppWebAccessClient();
        wac.getPOICompleted += new EventHandler<getPOICompletedEventArgs>(client_GetDataCompleted);
        wac.getPOIAsync(1);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }

}
void client_GetDataCompleted(object sender, getPOICompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //this.DataContext = e.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(e.Result.poiID);
}
```

On the server side there is following exception:

```
22:27:23,789 WARN  [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] Interceptor for {com.test}BBAppWebAccessService#{com.test}getPOI has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"com.test", local:"ID").
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:787) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:628) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:133) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:109) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.ServletControllerExt.invoke(ServletControllerExt.java:172) [:3.4.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:57) [:3.4.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:156) [:3.4.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFNonSpringServletExt.invoke(CXFNonSpringServletExt.java:90) [:3.4.1.GA]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 197; unexpected element (uri:"com.test", local:"ID"). Expected elements are <{}ID>]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:425) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:362) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:339) [:2.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:764) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
        ... 34 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 197; unexpected element (uri:"com.test", local:"ID"). Expected elements are <{}ID>
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:642) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:254) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:249) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:116) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.childElement(Loader.java:101) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.childElement(StructureLoader.java:243) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:478) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:459) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:242) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:176) [:2.2]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:360) [:2.2]
        ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"com.test", local:"ID"). Expected elements are <{}ID>
        ... 47 more
```

ClientConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BBAppWebAccessServiceSoapBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/BBAppWeb/HelloWorld"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BBAppWebAccessServiceSoapBinding"
                contract="SilverlightApplication1.ServiceReference1.BBAppWebAccess"
                name="BBAppWebAccessPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Message captured with Fiddler (Windows Phone):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <getPOI xmlns="com.test">
            <ID>1</ID>
        </getPOI><
    /s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Message captured with Fiddler (Axis2):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:getPOI xmlns:ns1="com.test">
            <ID>1</ID>
        </ns1:getPOI>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I fix it? The generated java code (Apache Axis2) works great.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: This could be a configuration problem. Have you tried generating the code using 'Add Service Reference' in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I tried it and I got the same error, too. But feel free to test it on your own and report about your results.

Comment: I'll need the service address.

Comment: There is no online service, because it is under development. I am sorry.

Comment: OK. If you post your config then I may still be able to help.

Comment: I have added the ClientConfig. I hope it is the right config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. When you are creating the WebService with Java EE you have to add all namespaces, otherwise you will get the errors above.
After fixing the *FaultException*, I got a *NullReferenceException*, which indicates that I have to fix the response handling, too.

Thanks a lot to **@calum**.

Here is a sample implementation of the WebService, which works together with Axis2 and the SLsvcUtil tool:

```
package com.test;

//imports here

@WebService(targetNamespace = "com.test")
public class BBAppWebAccess {
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace="com.test.poi")
    public POI getPOI(
            @WebParam(name="ID", targetNamespace="com.test.poi")
            int id) {

        return new POI(id);
    }
}
```

The new message looks like following:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <getPOI xmlns="com.test">
            <ID xmlns="com.test.poi">1</ID>
        </getPOI>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The new genereated *getPOI* class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getPOI", WrapperNamespace="com.test", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getPOI {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="com.test.poi", Order=0)]
    public int ID;

    public getPOI() {
    }

    public getPOI(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, you should mark this post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending the service the wrong type (I assume this as the error states that an unexpected element 'ID' was found and that means that your request is not properly formed).
Use fiddler (if possible) to see what you are sending to the server. You will probably be able to figure out what is happening and then you can update the generated code so that the correct type is sent.

Comment: I added both messages captured with Fiddler above, the only difference is the namespace and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Can you please post the definition of the getPOI class.

Comment: Code added, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the WrapperNamespace on the MessageContractAttribute? If not please post the fiddler output.

Comment: No change, it is the same fiddler message.

Comment: So after removing the wrapper namespace you still get <getPOI xmlns="com.test"> in the request?? You need to adjust the attributes until either the element is qualified (as in the other example) or there is no namespace at all (<getPOI>). The problem with the request is that the namespace is not qualified so the ID element is automatically in the com.test namespace instead of being unqualified. Try setting the wrapper namespace to an empty string (or the Namespace member of the MessageBodyMemberAttribute on the ID property).